# Set Attribute via code-behind to Xaml Object

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to set an Attribute to a Property, which is defined in Xaml.
Here is the Property (for example)

```
<Converter:PercentageConverter x:Key="percentageConverter" />
```

and I want to add an Attribute to this Property like this in code-behind:

```
PercentageConverter percentageConverter = this.Resources["percentageConverter"] as PercentageConverter;
SetAttribute(percentageConverter, XmlIgnoreAttribute);
```

In the SetAttribute Method is the 'magic' to add the Attribute, that can 'normally be declared like

> ```
> [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
> ```

```
public void PlayPauseCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myVlcControl.Play();
}
```

How can I implement this Magic in the SetAttribute method? I think via Reflection, but how exactly? Is is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(Object, Attribute[]). It adds class-level attributes to the target component instance.

[AddAttributes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xazd050.aspx)